# Can I split cells within a table?

Tags: google-docs

I have a table where each row might have one, two or three columns. For example, here is a similar table I made in LibreOffice Writer, using the split cell functionality:
[image: image of table with 1,2 or 3 columns depending on row]
As far as I can tell, Google Documents does not have "Split cell", only "Merge cell".

So I can do this by creating a table with six columns, then merging the appropriate combinations. However, this is fiddly and manual.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Not currently, according to the Google Docs forums. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/LfSsoCAWFZs

Answer (score 3):

splitting cells in two without inserting 1+ column is not yet supported, however you can easily **unmerge** merged cells in Google Docs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can copy the table wanted as independent and past it appropriately.
2. Because a new table has a blank line just above itself where you click and see the cursor blinking on and off, I recommend you go down the font size immediately above the pasted-table to 1 unit, reducing the split it may look like.
3. Now you can perform cells merge, unmerge, and move the ruler freely, without affecting other tables.
4. Furthermore, you should configure it.  Right-click on it and have fun.

For more information, I recommend you to format it.
It will not look like two tables (Right-click on it -> Table properties -> Table border > 0pt)